# PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

say I have 50 lines of ps code I want to run, a few examples below, I dont want to open 50 windows and run them separately, is there a way to just go to the next line once the first one is done?

```
.\Get-MessageTraceBySubject.ps1 -Days 3 -Subject "*favor*" -OutputFile c:\temp\favor-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv
.\Get-MessageTraceBySubject.ps1 -Days 3 -Subject "*errand*" -OutputFile c:\temp\errand-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv
.\Get-MessageTraceBySubject.ps1 -Days 3 -Subject "*greeting*" -OutputFile c:\temp\greeting-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv
```

tried -wait it failed

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If you're asking for an alternative to pasting multiple commands at the interactive prompt in order to execute them sequentially, paste them into a `.ps1` file and invoke the latter.

Comment: Why do you think you have to open 50 windows? Could you clarify what you've tried with an example and the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just create a txt file that contains the keywords you are looking for and then loop through the results.

```
$var = get-content .\keywords.txt
foreach ($filter in $var) {
.\Get-MessageTraceBySubject.ps1 -Days 3 -Subject "*$filter*" -OutputFile "c:\temp\$($filter)-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
}
```